# The ViewData item that has the key "my ID" is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, razor, model-binding

Trying to edit a foreign key value in a table. In the edit of my controller I create a viewbag item as a selectlist of the foreign table, with the selected value from the table I want to edit. I am able to populate the dropdownlistfor the correct field, and the correct value is selected. I added the id's to the edit(BIND"...") values, but when I pass the values, the modelstate is invalid.

The simplified Model:

```
 public class NOEDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int noeKey { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Patient patientID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Attending Physician")]
    public virtual Physician attendingPhysician { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Certifying Physician")]
    public virtual Physician certifyingPhysician { get; set; }

    //public IEnumerable<Physician> attendingEnum { get; set; }
    //public IEnumerable<Physician> certifyingEnum { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(35)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(25)]
    public string middleName { get; set; }

     [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
    public DateTime dob { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Gender")]
    public char? gender { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Address 1")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string addr1 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Address 2")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string addr2 { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string city { get; set; }
    [StringLength(2)]
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public string state { get; set; }
    [StringLength(9)]
    [Display(Name = "Zip")]
    public string zip { get; set; }


}
```

The simplified controller:

```
 public class NOEDetailsController : Controller
{
    private revDemo db = new revDemo();
    // GET: NOEDetails/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        NOEDetail nOEDetail = db.NOEDetails.Find(id);
        if (nOEDetail == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.attendingPhysicianSelectList = new SelectList(db.Physician, "physicianID", "Fullname", nOEDetail.attendingPhysician.physicianID);
        ViewBag.certifyingPhysicianSelectList = new SelectList(db.Physician, "physicianID", "Fullname", nOEDetail.certifyingPhysician.physicianID);
        return View(nOEDetail);
    }[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "noeKey,lastName,firstName,middleName,addr1,addr2,city,state,zip attendingPhysician,certifyingPhysician")] NOEDetail nOEDetail)
    {//^^ here I added the attendingPhysician, and certifyingPhysician code BY HAND to get rid of the first error, but then the model was incorrect.
        //ViewBag.attendingPhysicianSelectList = new SelectList(db.Physician, "physicianID", "Fullname", nOEDetail.attendingPhysician.physicianID);
        //ViewBag.certifyingPhysicianSelectList = new SelectList(db.Physician, "physicianID", "Fullname", nOEDetail.certifyingPhysician.physicianID);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(nOEDetail).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(nOEDetail);
    }
```

The View Item:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.attendingPhysician.physicianID, ViewBag.attendingPhysicianSelectList as SelectList,null, new { @class = "form-control"})
```

The issue is when I submit the data. The data is retrieved correctly but is being sent back to the controller as a selectlistitem instead of the value tied to the item, which is what I want. Help, please?

Comment: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'attendingPhysician.physicianID'.        is the error I get without the physicianID's in the BIND line. And the other error that I get is when I add the two physicianid labels to the edit(Bind"...") The ViewData item that has the key 'attendingPhysician.physicianID' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue as this guy, although he never really solves it, because the int that he creates representing the value is never actually tied to the entry in the database.          https://forums.asp.net/t/1823465.aspx?Adding+Foreign+key+DropDownList+to+create+view